# How to deploy webapp to Appscale from Google Plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: java, google-plugin-eclipse, google-app-engine, appscale

I'm developing a Java Webapplication using GWT and Google Plugin for Eclipse.
I started to use Appscale instead of Google App Engine, but not sure how to configure things to deploy webapp to appscale.
Is there anyone who accomplished this? If so, please let me know how to do it.

([There is no eclipse plugin dedicated for appscale](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appscale_community/7eLkS_pxn8A) as of August 26th 2013.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not upload your Java app by clicking "Deploy to App Engine" GUI button from Google Plugin for Eclipse, but instead, you can upload with Appscale command line client. (as of 2014-10-21)

You can follow the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse#Creating_a_Project) that GAE provides for writing an application in Eclipse.
The code layout discussed there is fully compatible with AppScale.

Make sure to use the correct version of the SDK described in AppScale's [FAQ](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki/FAQs#what-version-of-the-gae-api-do-you-support).

After that deploying your app on AppScale is as easy as typing `appscale deploy Guestbook` from the command line.

Comment: I saw the instruction page, and found following under "Uploading to Google App Engine" section: For a non-Maven application, click the Google button Google button icon in the Eclipse toolbar, and select Deploy to App Engine. Eclipse might prompt you for your administrator account username (your email address) and password. Enter your account information and click the Upload button to complete the upload. Does this action upload app to appscale? Or, this is only for GAE? And if I need to run command "appscale deploy Guestbook", in which directory should I run that command?

Comment: That's right, the Upload button works for GAE, not AppScale.

For you to deploy an app on AppScale, navigate into the directory with the AppScalefile and run the command `appscale deploy <path-to-app-dir>`.

In AppScale's [sample apps repo](https://github.com/AppScale/sample-apps/tree/master/java) you can find a set of Java sample apps that work on AppScale. This is not an exhaustive list.